# Copy selected input box with javascript doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, copy, clipboard, paste

For my programming culture I'm experimenting with audio html tag and audio sources, and OS clipboard. It's 3 days I'm trying to solve the issue exposed as follows.

### Situation

I have an html page on server with a js which has a bunch of code in it.
The js does a lot of things, among the others generates two inputs inserting where I need the appropriate html:

a text input:

```
<input type="text" id="titleToCopy" value="" />

and a button:

    <input type="button" value="Copy" onclick="copyTitleOnClipboard()"/>


Into the js code there are also these two functions

function execThings() //This execute some operations and also calls other functions
{
    console.log(arguments.callee.name);
    var dest = document.getElementById(myplayerID); // Gets my player by its ID
    var osrc = getOriginalPlayer().src;
    dest.src = osrc;
    updateTitleToCopy();
    copyTitleOnClipboard();
    stopOriginalPlayer();
}


function copyTitleOnClipboard() // This function select and copies to the Operative System clipboard the content of the related text input
{
    console.log(arguments.callee.name);
    var titleInput = document.getElementById("titleToCopy");
    titleInput.focus(); // The function works good with or without this line
    titleInput.select();

    var r = document.execCommand("copy");
    r = r === true ? "has been" : "not";

    console.log("Title " + r + " copied to clipboard");
}
```

For debugging purposes I added in both functions the row

```
console.log(arguments.callee.name);
```

In this way on Chrome console is shown the name of the function, so I can check if it starts execution.

### The Behavior

- If I click the button the related **onclick** function **copyTitleOnClipboard()** executes and copies the value of the input into the OS clipboard.
- If I write by hands the name of the function **copyTitleOnClipboard()** into the Google Chrome console it works too.

For me this means that the **copyTitleOnClipboard()** function per se works properly. In fact on the console in both cases I get the debug feedback thanks to the row:

```
console.log("Title " + r + " copied to clipboard");
```

which as expected returns the output
**Title has been copied to clipboard**

And if I paste elsewhere (for example into notepad) the content of the clipboard the result is the value of the text box input, as expected.

### The problem

The problem is that when the execution is due to the other function **execThings()**, which calls the **copyTitleOnClipboard()** function, it doesn't work anymore: the **copyTitleOnClipboard()** function is executed in fact on the console is shown its name as expected but I also get the fail feedback message:
**Title not copied to clipboard**
and if I paste the clipboard content in notepad it doesn't contain the text box value that has to be copied or is empty at all

### Questions

- Why calling the **copyTitleOnClipboard()** function from another function doesnt' work as if I call it by clicking the button or by hands by the Chrome console?
- How do I solve the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the call to `execThings` in a https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded callback and see, whether the behaviour is still strange.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can explain what are you trying to do inside the “exeThings()” function. Without that, it would be more like shooting in the dark.

Comment: @dj79 it sets an audio source of an audio palyer on the page I have updated the code copy the whole function content but I'm afraid it doesn't help very much though

Comment: @willywonka, it did help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replicate the issue you are facing.

Checkout this code here: https://jsfiddle.net/t1pe6zw8/

Open this link, wait for 5 seconds and see what happens.

Here is the explanation for the behavior:

I am assuming here that the `execThings()` function is triggered by some event that's not raised by user action.

> The basic JS method document.execCommand(), requires that it be triggered by user
>   interaction to prevent web pages from messing with the clipboard
>   without the user's knowledge. This is a security feature and is
>   enforced by every browser.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ execThings(); }, 5000);
});
```

This code above, once the document is ready, triggers the `execThings()` function after 5 seconds and since it's triggered without user action, it fails to copy the text.

Now, if you click `Click Me to Exec Things` button on JSFiddle link above, it triggers the same `execThings()` function, and it is able to copy the text.

You can get more details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Return_value

Now, I am not sure what are your use-cases, but you will need to get user action to copy the text.

Hope this helps!

Comment: oh I see... user action... that's it! great! Thanks

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Comment: I hope google will implement into google chrome developer console (and so other developer environments) a more precise message system so when programmers do such kind of mistakes will be advised properly so they can correct the code immediately going in the right direction instead of loosing days time looking for some thing that won't work... In the meantime stackoverflow is a great problem solver resource... Thanks!

Comment: Hahaha..let's hope! In any case, SO is great.

Answer (score 0):

eeeehhhmmm...

Sir I've copied your code and replaced `copyTitleOnClipboard()` with `execThings()` in the `onclick="copyTitleOnClipboard()"` of the button.... And it works properly, `execThings()` and `copyTitleOnClipboard()` are printed in the console and the value of the input box is copied to the clipboard and I verified that...

this clearly states that the problem is with the other code omitted from the question and replaced with the `//some other code` comment. Please include that code in addition to the code of the question because I think something there messes up the `execThings()` function.

Comment: Hi Saif, and thanks for trying to help me. I understand your point of view, I have done it. But I'm afraid it doesn't help very much because in the mentioned comment there are some statements and some other calls to other functions, which call other function... etc. To do what you need I have to be more specific and post the content of the html page, and the content of all javascript in it to check any possible interaction with them all. It could be difficult to do

Comment: Well, for the time of being, I'm afraid I can't help you. sorry :(

Comment: Saif, Thanks for trying any way though :-) . May I ask some more specifications? To make it work properly as in your response you had to click on the button?

Comment: Yes, I clicked the button. I didn't try calling the functions from the console, though.

Comment: this was my mistake too, in fact I was trying to make it work without my interaction (so without any click) because I wanted to automate the whole process, but it wasn't possible as specified in dj79's answer. Anyway thank you so much for your time.